# Force per-machine Context when publishing MSI via GPO

Tags: wix, windows-installer, gpo

I've got an MSI build with WIX. The Package has `InstallScope="perMachine"` attribute.

My product depends on some 3rd party products of certain versions. MSI checks prerequisites with `Upgrade` element.

I'd like to deploy my MSI via AD/GPO. Deployment under Computer configuration is successful, but I want published (not assigned) deployment under User Configuration. In this case users can see my installation in *Programs and Features - Install a program from the network* and may select: to install or not to install my product.

But published deployment fails.
There is part of MSI log:

```
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:906]: Product {D4_____________F9} is admin assigned: LocalSystem owns the publish key.
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:906]: Product {D4_____________F9} is managed.
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:906]: Running product '{D4____________F9}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.

    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:906]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:906]: Determined that existing product (either this product or the product being upgraded with a patch) is installed per-user.
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:906]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '1'.
```

*...skipped...*

```
    Action begin 16:22:32: FindRelatedProducts.
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:922]: FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-user.  Related install for product '{69_______________BD}' is per-machine.  Skipping...
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:922]: FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-user.  Related install for product '{69_______________BD}' is per-machine.  Skipping...
    MSI (c) (38:CC) [16:22:32:922]: FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-user.  Related install for product '{DD______________23}' is per-machine.  Skipping...
    Action end 16:22:32: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
```

And then MSI fails, because prerequisites are not found.

So my questions are: why installation context is switched to per-user? How to prevent it? Maybe there is a way to suppress skipping FindRelatedProducts in per-user context?

Comment: My guess is that you're not assigning per machine if you have this in the User Configuration. You probably know more about this than I do, but I think you need a per machine assiggn for a per machine install.

Comment: When assigning via Computer Configuration GPO, user has no ability to choose - whether install or not to install product - it will be installed in any way after rebooting workstation. User can control installation only in User Configuration GPO (published deploy).